# How to use bootstrap to make ASP gridview be responsive

Tags: asp.net, gridview, bootstrap-4

I meet a problem about using bootstrap to create responsive GridView.
I see an example in https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/47548d/responsive-grid-view-in-Asp-Net/?,
but the main problem is if the column width is each different in gridview, 
how to set its md,xs,sm,lg css class to meet gridview its original width style,
Is there good way to make that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add necessary bootstrap files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <asp:GridView ID="grdPDFView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Files">
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```